# R: How get file name with Quanteda: char_segment

Tags: r, split, text-mining, quanteda

I am using  char_segment from Quanteda library to separate multiple documents from one file separatted by a pattern, this command works great and easily! (I did try with str_match and strsplit but without success).

Lamentably I am unable to get the filename as a Variable, this is key to next analysis.[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl8jA.png)

Example of my commands:

```
Library(quanteda)
doc <- readtext(paste0("PATH/*.docx"))
View(doc)

docc=char_segment(doc$text,  pattern = ",", remove_pattern = TRUE)
```

Please any suggestion or other options to split documents are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get the list of your docx files first, it will yield the name of the files. Then run the char_segment function on them them by a lapply, loop, or purrr::map()

The following code assumes that your target documents are stored in a directory called "docx" within your working directory.

```
library(quanteda)
library(readtext)  ## Remember to include in your posts the libraries required to replicate the code.


list_of_docx <- list.files(path = "./docx", ## Looks inside the ./docx directory
                       full.names = TRUE,   ## retrieves the full path to the documents
                       pattern = "[.]docx$", ## retrieves al documents whose names ends in ".docx"
                       ignore.case = TRUE)  ## ignores the letter case of the document's names
```

### Preparing the for loop

```
df_docx <- data.frame() ## Create an empty dataframe to store your data

for (d in seq_along(list_of_docx)) {  ## Tell R to run the loop/iterate along the number of elements within thte list of doccument paths
    temp_object <-readtext(list_of_docx[d])
    temp_segmented_object <- char_segment(temp_object$text, pattern = ",", remove_pattern = TRUE)
    temp_df <- as.data.frame(temp_segmented_object)
    colnames(temp_df) <- "segments"
    temp_df$title <- as.character(list_of_docx[d])  ## Create a variable with the title of the source document
    temp_df <- temp_df[, c("title", "segments")]
    df_docx <- rbind(df_docx, temp_df) ## Append each dataframe to the previously created empty dataframe
    rm(temp_df, temp_object, d)
    df_docx
 }


head(df_docx)
```

Comment: Sorry I am basic in R. Could give an example to add file name with lapply  or a loop. Thanks in advance

Comment: My file contain multiple documents, then the row number for doc_id is not the same that the number of row documents when I separate with the pattern.

Comment: Hello Rodrigo. I updated the answer to be more thorough. Please check it.

Comment: wow! work great!! Thanks for your time and effort with your example!

Answer (score 0):

You should have names of Word files already:

```
require(readtext)
data_dir <- system.file("extdata/", package = "readtext")
readtext(paste0(data_dir, "/word/*"))

readtext object consisting of 6 documents and 0 docvars.    
# data.frame [6 × 2]
  doc_id                                 text                
  <chr>                                  <chr>               
1 21Parti_Socialiste_SUMMARY_2004.doc    "\"[pic]\nRésu\"..."
2 21vivant2004.doc                       "\"http://www\"..." 
3 21VLD2004.doc                          "\"http://www\"..." 
4 32_socialisti_democratici_italiani.doc "\"DIVENTARE \"..." 
5 UK_2015_EccentricParty.docx            "\"The Eccent\"..." 
6 UK_2015_LoonyParty.docx                "\"The Offici\"..."
```

They are passed to **quanteda**'s downstream objects as document names.

Comment: In your example?.Where I set up the pattern to separate documents? This is my problem, I can not get names of files when I separate documents.

Comment: I dont have problems to get file names from

Comment: I dont have problems to get file names with readtext, but this column (file id) dessapear when I separated the document  with char_segment

Comment: try `docnames()` on a corpus, tokens, or DFM.

Answer (score 0):

[Example when I read text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUfQO.png)
This is my problem, when I separe documents by ###*

[When I use Char segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zMdp.png)